# ASP.NET MVC6 "The binary operator Equal is not defined"

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have this model:

```
[Table("tblDbFile")]
public class DbFile
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Engine { get; set; }
    public string Hash { get; set; }
    public long Size { get; set; }
    public DbDir Directory { get; set; }
}

[Table("tblDbDir")]
public class DbDir
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DbDir Parent { get; set; }
}
```

If I try to execute the line `_context.DbFile.Where(n => n.Directory == Dir)` I get this error:

(`Dir` is of type DbDir)

Message:

> InvalidOperationException: The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.Nullable`1[System.Guid]' and 'Models.DbDir'.

How can I resolve this? Using `_context.DbFile.Where(n => n.Directory.Id == Dir.Id)` works but this is not an option for me because first of all, I have to use these types of referencing a lot and second, `Dir` could be null.

I already tried:

- overriding the `==` and `!=` operators of the objects, which does work, but it no longer optimizes the SQL query and instead does the comparison in C#.
- Trying to declare Dir as `DbDir?` (fails)
- Using `n.Directory.Equals(Dir)` (same issue as with overriding `==`)
- Using `Dir??.Id` in the expression (fails)

Comment: Which version of EF Core is this? There were problems in older versions that could lead to this exception message that have already been fixed, but it's possible that other problems still remain. This particular exception message clearly points to a bug in EF: it's complaining about a particular comparison that you're not performing. Either EF's exception message should say that what *you're* doing is not supported, or it should translate it appropriately. If it persists in the latest version and isn't already known, it may be worth reporting on their issue tracker.

Comment: @hvd 7.0.0-rc1-16348

Comment: 7.0.* are the old version numbers, this version numbering was dropped after rc1. The current version is 1.1.0. See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/releases. It's also available on NuGet as [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/) rather than [EntityFramework.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Core/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query generator has no way of translating your operators, as you have found. You *have* to use the version that you don't like:

```
_context.DbFile.Where(n => n.Directory.Id == Dir.Id)
```

And yes, this is problematic in the `null` case; so... in that case you will need to write it differently:

```
if(Dir == null) {
    query = _context.DbFile.Where(n => n.Directory == null);
}
else {
    query = _context.DbFile.Where(n => n.Directory.Id == Dir.Id);
}
```

As an aside; if you also have `n.DirectoryId`, you may find it convenient to use that instead:

```
if(Dir == null) {
    query = _context.DbFile.Where(n => n.DirectoryId == null);
}
else {
    var id = Dir.Id;
    query = _context.DbFile.Where(n => n.DirectoryId == id);
}
```

Comment: _"this is problematic in the null case"_ - why though? Isn't the expression merely inspected, rather than executed?

Comment: "The query generator has no way of translating your operators" -- It certainly has a way. It could be unimplemented, or it could be implemented incorrectly, but it's not impossible, and the exception message suggests to me that EF is attempting to implement it.

Comment: @CodeCaster indeed, it is an expression tree being pulled apart - but: that doesn't mean that every engine can understand every conceivable setup. As it happens, values of null members is one that that tends to not have great support, and as such is problematic. Although to be fair, it is not clear that there is a *valid* interpretation of something which - if executed - would throw an exception.

Comment: @Marc disregard my previous comment, I shouldn't be asking new questions under an existing answer. Thanks for your explanation anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of `Dir` being null can easily be fixed by checking if it is null, and only if it is not null then you compare the Ids, like this:

```
_context.DbFile.Where(n => Dir == null || n.Directory.Id == Dir.Id)
```

As an alternative, if `n.Directory` can also be null and that should match with `Dir == null`, then use this:

```
_context.DbFile.Where(n => (Dir == null && n.Directory == null)
                        || (Dir != null && n.Directory.Id == Dir.Id))
```

Comment: Note: you need to be a little cautious with this type of complexity - it can very quickly lead to very sub-optimal generated queries. It depends a lot on the tool being used, obviously - all I'm saying is: make sure you look at what it is being generated.

Comment: @MarcGravell I just checked. The query is `N'SELECT [n].[Id], [n].[DirectoryId], [n].[Engine], [n].[Hash], [n].[Name], [n].[OwnerId], [n].[Size]
FROM [tblDbFile] AS [n]
WHERE (@__p_0 = 1 AND [n].[DirectoryId] IS NULL) OR (@__p_1 = 1 AND ([n].[DirectoryId] = @__Dir_Id_2))',N'@__p_0 bit,@__p_1 bit,@__Dir_Id_2 uniqueidentifier',@__p_0=0,@__p_1=1,@__Dir_Id_2='3D4AF7D3-18CE-48F0-1E75-08D4298C31D6'`. Certainly more complex but still does the comparison in SQL rather than C#

Comment: @AyrA yeah, that's the kind of thing that would give me sleepless nights; I'm very very fussy about my SQL :)